# Slim can be used for html parsing?

Tags: php, slim

I'm looking for a simple framework that allow me to scrape some data on the web. In the past I used Slim to made a rest API, but now I'm going to make a web scraper. I already have experience with `simple html dom parser`, but I want to know if I Slim have a parser functionality. 

In the documentation I can't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common frameworks are not really suited for this task and PHP is usually not a good choice as a language for scraping. There is a framework called Scrapy written in Python which is specific for scraping websites:

http://scrapy.org/

Comment: unfortunately I don't know python

Answer (score 0):

Slim offers just a quick and simple app skeleton: routes and middleware. There are no integrated tools for anything else.

I doubt there's a framework out there (as in web app framework: Zend/Laravel/Symfony etc.) providing anything that automates/helps with what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use PHP for web scraping, consider purchasing https://www.phparch.com/books/phparchitects-guide-to-web-scraping-with-php/.